# Python os.path.isdir() does not consider a folder as a folder

Tags: python, os.path, python-os

I was doing "robot" which it should run through the contents of the folder and folders inside the folders, and save in excel a list of files lying there in the format. Everything is doing great before going inside the folder which is located in a folder. Like fixedtest --> test --> insidetest. The issue that when I run debug, passing through "if not os.path.isdir(file): " for some reason, he fulfills this condition, considering that this folder is not a folder.
I'm beginner in python and os library, so may be idk something and how it's work, but everything seems to be correct and it's confused. What I should to change, how I can solve the problem?

```
import openpyxl
import os


def add_row(rowN, folderName, fileName, ext):
    sheet.cell(row=rowN, column=1).value = rowN
    sheet.cell(row=rowN, column=2).value = folderName
    sheet.cell(row=rowN, column=3).value = fileName
    sheet.cell(row=rowN, column=4).value = ext

path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
folders = []
i = 0
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1'] = 'Number of row'
sheet['B1'] = 'Folder where file located'
sheet['C1'] = 'File name'
sheet['D1'] = 'File extension'

folders.append(path)

for folder in folders:
    try:
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
           
            if not os.path.isdir(file):
                i = i + 1
                add_row(i, os.path.basename(folder), os.path.splitext(file)[0], 
    os.path.splitext(file)[1])
            else:
                folders.append(file)

    except:
        print(folders)
wb.save("test.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Comment: `os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, file))` -- you need to give the full pathname.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Do you expect that the `openpyxl` stuff is relevant to the problem you are experiencing? If so, why? If not, can you think of a way to remove or replace that part of the code to simplify it, while still showing the problem?

Comment: @Barmar it works, but now the program doesn't read files in this folder, why is that?

Comment: You also need to append the joined pathname.

Comment: It looks like you're duplicating the functionality of `os.walk()`. Why not just use that?

Comment: @Barmar Now everything is correct, thank you a lot :)